# Scrollable property in TabView Primefaces

Tags: primefaces, scrollable, tabview

im having this problem when using primefaces, with this:

```
<p:tabView id="Details" widgetVar="tabPanelDetailsWidget" scrollable="true" >
```

in the app, the tabs (i have like 14 of them) apear in different rows (not each in a different row), with no scrolling arrows on the sides.

do i need to add something else in the tabview for this to work? (tabs are static btw)

thanks in advance

Comment: What primefaces version is being used?

Comment: im using primefaces 3.5

Comment: I think you talk something like http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/tabviewScroll.jsf this

Comment: yes, thats exactly what i want to use

Comment: can you write your code?